# actionscript3 ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData

Tags: flash, class, actionscript, bitmap

I'm a designer trying my hands in the world of code.  So far, I've been able to figure things out, but I've finally hit a wall.  I'm working in Flash here, so the possibility does not escape me that it might not be the code, but a setting.  Also, being new, it's possible that the answer has been in front of me this whole time and I'm just going down a rabbit hole.

Anyway, I'm working on a simple game that requires walls to disappear when a character is underneath them, then reappear once he leaves.  I asked for help on this and was able to get some code in the form of a separate class file.  This is awesome and bad in that

-awesome, as I have code that works, but...
-being new at coding , I never worked with classes, and now that I've applied it to my own project, it doesn't work.  Troubleshoothing has now become much more difficult.

After struggling to find an answer, I think it's finally come to the point that I must ask for help.

Everything compiles nicely, but I am immediately greeted with the following output error:

```
"Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL ""\flashDemoCS5.5-47.swf
[SWF] ""\flashDemoCS5.5-47.swf - 8512188 bytes after decompression
ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
    at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
    at flash.display::BitmapData()
    at Wall()[""\Wall.as:15]
    at wall_003()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at Wall()[""\Wall.as:13]
    at wall()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at flashDemoCS5_fla::MainTimeline()
Cannot display source code at this location.
"
```

The code, as given to me, works in a demo, which itself is simply attached.  The .fla demonstrating the capabilities has no coding in it whatsoever.  I'll post that first.  It is Wall.as and it is located in the same folder as the main .fla file:

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;


    public class Wall extends MovieClip {

        var bmp:BitmapData;

        public function Wall() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hideWall, false, 0, false);
            bmp = new BitmapData (this.width, this.height, true, 0);
            bmp.draw(this);
        }

        public function hideWall(e:Event){
            if(bmp.hitTest(new Point(0, 0), 0, this.globalToLocal(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)))) {
                this.visible = false;
            }else{
                this.visible = true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The code attached to the main .fla file is in its own layer on frame one:

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);


stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; // or other scale modes...
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);

function resizeHandler(e:Event):void{
            trace(stage.stageWidth + "x" + stage.stageHeight);
}

;
var animationState:String = "idle";
var mirrorState:String = "walk";
var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

//collisions
var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;

//player collision points (relative to anchor point)
var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-50,100);
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(50,100);
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,75);
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,150);

//button press
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;

//scrollspeed
var xSpeed:int = 0;
var ySpeed:int = 0;

var speedConstant:int = 5;

var friction:Number = 0.80;

//identify player location
var scrollX:int = 0;
var scrollY:int = 0;

//identify current level
var currentLevel:int = 1;

//next level function
function nextLevel():void{
     currentLevel++;
     //trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
     if(currentLevel == 2){
          gotoLevel2();
     }
     if(currentLevel == 3){
          gotoLevel1();
     }
}

//level 3 is the same as level 1.  3 will go back to 1 in the code so level 2 can be accessed agin.
function gotoLevel1():void{
    back.other.gotoAndStop(1);
    back.visuals.gotoAndStop(1);
    back.collisions.gotoAndStop(1);
    scrollX = 0;
    scrollY = 0;
    keyCollected = false;
    back.other.doorKey.visible = true;
    doorOpen = false;
    back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(1);
    currentLevel = 1;
}

function gotoLevel2():void{
     back.other.gotoAndStop(2); //updates door and key
     back.visuals.gotoAndStop(2); //updates the visuals
     back.collisions.gotoAndStop(2); //updates the collisions
     scrollX = 0; //resets the player's x position in the new level
     scrollY = 500; //resets the player's y position in the new level
     keyCollected = false; //resets the keyCollected variable
     back.other.doorKey.visible = true; //makes the key visible again
     doorOpen = false; //resets the doorOpen variable
     back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(1); //makes the door return to its locked image
}

function loop(e:Event):void
{


    if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        //trace("leftBumping");
        leftBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x,player.y + rightBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        //trace("rightBumping");
        rightBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rightBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x,player.y + upBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        //trace("upBumping");
        upBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        upBumping = false;
    }

    if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x,player.y + downBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        //trace("downBumping");
        downBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        downBumping = false;
    }

    if (leftPressed)
    {
        xSpeed -=  speedConstant;

    }
    else if (rightPressed)
    {
        xSpeed +=  speedConstant;

    }

    if (upPressed)
    {
        ySpeed -=  speedConstant;

    }
    else if (downPressed)
    {
        ySpeed +=  speedConstant;

    }

    //colision react
    if (leftBumping)
    {
        if (xSpeed < 0)
        {
            xSpeed *=  -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (rightBumping)
    {
        if (xSpeed > 0)
        {
            xSpeed *=  -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (upBumping)
    {
        if (ySpeed < 0)
        {
            ySpeed *=  -0.5;
        }
    }

    if (downBumping)
    {
        if (ySpeed > 0)
        {
            ySpeed *=  -0.5;
        }
    }
    if (ySpeed && xSpeed || xSpeed || ySpeed> 10){
        (ySpeed + xSpeed)/2;
        trace(ySpeed + xSpeed);
        trace(ySpeed);
        trace(xSpeed);
    }
    else if(ySpeed && xSpeed || xSpeed || ySpeed < -10){
        (ySpeed + xSpeed)/2;
        trace(ySpeed + xSpeed);
        trace(ySpeed);
        trace(xSpeed);
    }
    //smoothes scrolling
    xSpeed *=  friction;
    ySpeed *=  friction;

    scrollX -=  xSpeed;
    scrollY -=  ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;

        //key controls
    if(keyCollected == false){ // if we still haven't collected the key
if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.doorKey)){ // and if the player collides with the key
back.other.doorKey.visible = false; // hide the key from view
keyCollected = true; // set our Boolean to true
}
}
    if(doorOpen == false){ // if the door hasn't been opened yet
     if(keyCollected == true){ // and if the player has already collected the key
          if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){ // check if the door and the player are touching
               // if all of these conditions are met...
               back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2); // ...switch the door's image to its 2nd frame
               doorOpen = true; // ...set the variable to true//level change.  Move this later.
if(doorOpen && player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){
          //proceed to the next level if the player is touching an open door
          nextLevel();
     }
          }
     }

    if(doorOpen || player.hitTestObject(back.other.openDoor)){
        nextLevel();
    }
    }


    //animation
    if (leftPressed || rightPressed || downPressed || xSpeed > speedConstant || xSpeed < ( speedConstant *-1 ) ){
        animationState = "walk";
    }else if(upPressed || upPressed && rightPressed || upPressed && leftPressed){
        animationState = "walk_up";
    }else{ 
        player.prevFrame();
    }


    //makse player face direction he/she is going;
    if (leftPressed && !rightPressed)
    {
        player.scaleX = -.7;
    }
    else if (rightPressed && !leftPressed)
    {
        player.scaleX = .7;
    }
    //stop animation
    if (player.currentLabel != animationState)
    {
        player.gotoAndStop(animationState);
    }

}






function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = true;

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = true;

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = true;

    }

    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = false;

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = false;

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = false;

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Hopefully I have provided everything that is needed.

Comment: Where had u instantiated the "Wall.as" class? Also have you checked the `width` and `height` providing to the `BitmapData` object instantiation?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new MovieClip, it has no content and its dimensions are zero. As Wall extends MovieClip, this is what you are doing (extending a class means you are using it as a template to add extra functionality to, to put it very simply) - you then create a bitmap based on the dimensions of the parent MovieClip (0x0) and attempt to draw it to it. This is what's breaking your code.

I'm assuming you are using Flash, and not Flex/Flash Builder, if so do you have a graphic which you want to use for the wall? If you convert it to a MovieClip, right-click and select 'Properties' in the library, then select 'Export for ActionScript'it will create you a custom class for it. When you create a new instance of this object, it contains the graphic data.

If you then want to add custom functionality, create a class which extends this *instead of MovieClip*, but make sure you call **super()** in the constructor (the function with the same name as the class).

Let me know if this helps...